# I can't enable the WIFI in any way

Tags: wifi, appcenter, drivers, internet

The wifi logo doesn't show up in the top right corner and I don't have the option to connect wirelessly to any routers.
I tried every command I could find to solve this problem but none of them have worked so far. It was suggested that I need a driver from the app center, but I didn't find a "drivers" tab there. What could be a solution to this problem?

I have installed Windows on this laptop before and the wifi worked just fine.
The output for `lshw -C network` is:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: e8:6a:64:98:ab:bf
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:33 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b00fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

Comment: I think we can help you better if we know it is your wifi card. You can have all this information with the `lshw -C network` command or `lspci`.

Comment: I tried lshw -C network, and the result was: *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0

Comment: and 
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: e8:6a:64:98:ab:bf
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full

Answer (score 0):

Now we have the wifi card model I can answer you.

It would seem that other people have them problem in Ubuntu 18.04 and elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, currently elementary Hera 5.1 is under version 18.04 of Ubuntu

So you can follow this answer on the Ubuntu StackExchange [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071334/1013655)

---

> **As far as I can tell, at the time of writing this, there is not yet a Wifi Driver for the Realtek RTL8821CE in the official Ubuntu
>   Repositories.**
>
> answer by @pHeLiOn in https://askubuntu.com/

---

Hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.